# Popover Bootstrap Card on Hover

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, popover

I have a Button for example that has the popover data toggle:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="User Info">Popover with Title</button>
```

The JS code that is associated with this popover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        trigger : 'hover',
        html : true,
        content : '<div class="container mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center"> <div class="card p-3"> <div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <div class="image"> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522075469751-3a6694fb2f61?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80" class="rounded" width="155"> </div><div class="ml-3 w-100"> <h4 class="mb-0 mt-0">Alex Morrision</h4> <span>Senior Journalist</span> <div class="p-2 mt-2 bg-primary d-flex justify-content-between rounded text-white stats"> <div class="d-flex flex-column"> <span class="articles">Articles</span> <span class="number1">38</span> </div><div class="d-flex flex-column"> <span class="followers">Followers</span> <span class="number2">980</span> </div><div class="d-flex flex-column"> <span class="rating">Rating</span> <span class="number3">8.9</span> </div></div><div class="button mt-2 d-flex flex-row align-items-center"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary w-100">Chat</button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary w-100 ml-2">Follow</button> </div></div></div></div></div>'
    });
});
```

CSS for the popover Bootstrap card:

```
.card {
    width: 400px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff
}

.stats {
    background: #f2f5f8 !important;
    color: #000 !important
}

.articles {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a1aab9
}

.number1 {
    font-weight: 500
}

.followers {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a1aab9
}

.number2 {
    font-weight: 500
}

.rating {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a1aab9    
}

.number3 {
    font-weight: 500
}
```

However, when I hover over the card, with the appropriate CSS, it will show the default popover background behind the bootstrap card that is with it.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Unclear. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover',
      html: true,
      content: '<div class="card p-3"> <div class="d-flex align-items-center"> <div class="image"> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522075469751-3a6694fb2f61?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80" class="rounded" width="155"> </div><div class="ml-3 w-100"> <h4 class="mb-0 mt-0">Alex Morrision</h4> <span>Senior Journalist</span> <div class="p-2 mt-2 bg-primary d-flex justify-content-between rounded text-white stats"> <div class="d-flex flex-column"> <span class="articles">Articles</span> <span class="number1">38</span> </div><div class="d-flex flex-column"> <span class="followers">Followers</span> <span class="number2">980</span> </div><div class="d-flex flex-column"> <span class="rating">Rating</span> <span class="number3">8.9</span> </div></div><div class="button mt-2 d-flex flex-row align-items-center"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary w-100">Chat</button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary w-100 ml-2">Follow</button> </div></div></div></div>'
    });
});
```

```css
.popover-title { display: none !important; }

.popover {
  max-width: 500px !important;
}

.popover-header{
display: none !important;  
}

.popover-body {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.card{
  border: none !important;
}

.card {
    width: 400px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff
}

.stats {
    background: #f2f5f8 !important;
    color: #000 !important
}

.articles {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a1aab9
}

.number1 {
    font-weight: 500
}

.followers {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a1aab9
}

.number2 {
    font-weight: 500
}

.rating {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #a1aab9    
}

.number3 {
    font-weight: 500
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="User Info">Popover with Title</button>
```

**Live Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/7fnqw418/

**P.S**: You can comment out the `.popover-header` class if you wish to display the popover header

Comment: It seems that this displays the popover card more properly, however it glitches in and out when you try to hover over the button again. @Salvino

Comment: That's because of the limited space here in stack overflow snippet runner. Try it in Jsfiddle. I've attached the link for you to see @Bubbycolditz

Answer (score 0):

First, rename your css class `.card`.

```
.custom-card {
    width: 400px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff
}
```

If you just want to apply your style do this :

```
<div class="custom-card">
```

If you want to mix bootstrap style and yours, you can add multiple classes to a single DOM element.
Rules given in later classes (or which are more specific) override.

```
<div class="card custom-card">
```